# regular expression to extract number from string

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I want to extract number from string. This is the string

```
#all/30
```

All I want is `30`. How can I extract?
I try to use :

```
echo "#all/30" | sed 's/.*\/([^0-9])\..*//'
```

But nothing happen.
How should I write for the regular expression?
Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below sed command,

```
$ echo "#all/30" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\)[^0-9]*/\1/'
30
```

- `[^0-9]*` `[^...]` is a negated character class. It matches any character but not the one inside the negated character class. `[^0-9]*` matches zero or more non-digit characters.
- `\([0-9]\+\)` Captures one or more digit characters.
- `[^0-9]*` Matches zero or more non-digit characters.
- Replacing the matched characters with the chars inside group 1 will give you the number `30`

Comment: Finally, it works. I never thought it should be a long-code-regex.
By the way, thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 4):

You may consider using grep to extract the numbers from a simple string like this.

```
echo "#all/30" | grep -o '[0-9]\+'
```

- `-o` option shows only the matching part that matches the pattern.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Both of answer give me what I need sir. I just need `30` for output.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "all/30" | sed 's/[^0-9]*\/\([0-9][0-9]*\)/\1/'
```

Avoid writing '.*' as it consumes entire string. Default matches are always **greedy**.

Comment: `echo "all/30" | sed 's#[^0-9]*/\([0-9]\{1,\}\)#\1#'`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "all/30" | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
# OR
echo "all/30" | sed 's#.*/##'
# OR
echo "all/30" | sed 's#.*\([0-9]*\)#\1#'
```

without more info about possible input string we can only assume that structure is `#all/` followed by the number (only)